# X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC) repeatedly mode not end at last position

Tags: xmouse

I use X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC) program at repeatedly while the button is down mode.

When I release the button it is not ending at last position.

In picture is end at one sometimes but I need every time.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try to simplify the code. Issue only one character as the ultimate test of the concept, then instead of WAITMS try the option of "Delay between simulated keystrokes" etc.